# Rails build a template that the user can build

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is more of a general question about how to design a part of my app. The goal is to allow the user to create a template or a ordering of the sequence of the tasks. Then the user could select which objects from another model that would fill in the order of the template model. So basically the template is a ordering of tasks that can repeat, once the user selects the other tasks that will fill the template. I want the user to be able to reuse the template to create different orderings based on the single template. What I was thinking was creating a template model that would look like:

```
model Template
  order:string
  number_of_unique_tasks:integer
```

I would two more models that would store the tasks and the like:

```
model Tasks
  has_many :list_tasks
  #some properties
model List
  has_many :list_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: list_tasks
model ListTask
  belongs_to :lists
  belongs_to :tasks
  order:integer
```

So I want to use the `Template` model to build the `List`. Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Comment: By 'order' do you mean as in a product order from a vendor, or a sequence of objects?

Comment: @PinnyM a sequence of objects, I have updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Ok, firstly are the objects in the template set always going to be of a single specific class (`Object`)?  Also, you have a field `number_of_objects` which indicates that each object in the template set should have a quantity - is that right?  Lastly, can you suggest some other class name than `Object` since that class is already taken by ruby?

Comment: @PinnyM Yes the template will always be a specific class now called `tasks`. I was thinking that the `number_of_unique_tasks` would be helpful in determining the form to let the user choose the ordering fo the `tasks` so yes the `tasks` should have a quantity.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the Template model should resemble the List model.  It should have a descriptive name and a set of tasks.  When building a list off the template, the tasks associated with that template should be copied to a new list using the same sequence.  Something like this:

```
#table templates
# id: integer
# name: string
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :template_tasks, order: sequence
  has_many :tasks, through: :template_tasks

  def to_list
    list = List.new
    list.list_tasks = template_tasks.map{|t| 
      ListTask.new(task_id: t.task_id, order: t.sequence) 
    }
    list
  end
end

#table template_tasks
# id: integer
# template_id: integer
# task_id: integer
# sequence: integer
class TemplateTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :template
end
```